# Node com mongodb não iniciando aplicação

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando subir uma aplicação em *Node* com `mongoose`, (estou estudando, livro MEAN casa do código) e me gera o seguinte erro ao tentar iniciar o arquivo `server.js` onde inicio minha aplicação em Node, veja abaixo.

[image: comando para iniciar o server NODE]

Abaixo está meu arquivo server.js.

```js
var http = require('http');

var app = require('./config/express')();

require('./config/database.js')('mongodb://localhost/contatooh');

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){
 console.log('Express server executando na porta ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

OBS: o caminho do arquivo `bson.node` está correto, e o arquivo é existente na pasta.

Abaixo esta o arquivo de conexão com o banco *MongoDB*.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(uri){
    mongoose.connect(uri);

    mongoose.connection.on('connected', function(){
        console.log('Mongoose ! conectado em '+uri);
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function(){
        console.log('Mongoose ! Desconectado de '+uri);
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('error', function(erro){
        console.log('Mongoose ! erro na conecxão  '+erro);
    });

    process.on('SIGINT', function(){
        mongoose.connection.close(function(){
            console.log('Mongoose ! Desconectado pelo término da aplicação');
            process.exit(0);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Olá, blz? vc tem esse codigo no github?
...estou achando estranha a linha 5: require('./config/database.js')('mongodb://localhost/contatooh');

Comment: Opa ! blz e vc ?
Obrigado pelo retorno, eu compartilhei no github para que possa dar uma olhadinha.
Link: https://github.com/LucasPiresDev/mean_stack
vlw !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, tenho algumas suspeitas:

1º - tente rodar esse projeto a partir de outra pasta: pode ser algo referente a permissões do windows ou algum firewall que tá bloqueando o processo...

2º - A versão do node - eu rodei em um ambiente linux na nuvem (AWS-cloud9) o seu projeto, usei o node v6.11.2 - mas tive que alterar a linha 4 no database.js:

```
    mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Espero que isso te dê uma luz.

Comment: Opa, blz Valter !
Cara, faz sentido as duas suspeitas, vou ter que testar em outro ambiente para ver se não é o S.O. que parou esse serviço. Caso isso não funcione tentarei mudar a versão do Node, estou na versão 8.11.2, então eu teria que instalar essa versão que comentou.
Farei os teste e comento aqui o resultado de ambos, Vlw!

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e nada, voltei versão do node e coloquei em outra maquina, e mesmo assim não conseguir fazer rodar.

Bom eu fiz o seguinte teste, tirei o modulo mongoose e deixei mongo puro, e tentei rodar uma consulta simples pelo terminal e não acontece nada ao executar. Não sei mas o que fazer .

Comment: Problema RESOLVIDO, eu estava usando o driver do mongodb desatualizado, fazendo a atualização tudo funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram para encontrar um solução, espero que minha experiência sirva para ajudar alguém.Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar futuros erros de deprecation, a correção mais recente é esta:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/your_database', 
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).
    catch(error => handleError(error));

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)

mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    logError(err);
});

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

module.exports = mongoose
```

Funciona na versão 5.7.1 do mongoose. Fonte: [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#)